# Backbone.js events not firing when clicking on Icon-Font-Icon (sometimes text) on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

My Backbone click events won't fire when clicking on buttons with icon fonts (like  Icon).

One view e.g. looks like this:

```
var NetworkStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: _.template(Helper.view('network/status')),
events: {
    'click a': 'navigate'
},
navigate: function (el)
{
    Backbone.history.navigate($(el.target).attr('href'), true);
    return false;
},
render: function ()
{
    this.$el.html(this.template(userlocation.toJSON()));

    return this;
}
```

});

In the template the a"button" looks like this (yeah, it's bootstrap ;)):

```
<a href="/link" class="btn"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Über</a>
```

Have you got any idea why these events will fire when clicking on the borders, paddings and freespace of the button but won't fire when clicking on the icon (and sometimes on the text)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other events? Maybe some other event fires and thus this event never "sees" the click.

Comment: Well, I just noticed: the events sometimes will get fired, but wrong and you'll (in the link example) get yanked to the main view (router main route /)...

Comment: Nope. In this particular view there are no other events... - In other views I have some similar events, but all events are done via Backbones eventDelegate...

Answer (score 3):

The solution (thanks to @nekaab !) that worked for me:

change el.target to el.currentTarget, so the navigate function will look like this:

```
navigate: function (el)
{        
    Backbone.history.navigate($(el.currentTarget).attr('href'), true);
    return false;
}
```

Hopefully this will help :) - thanks again for all your answeres!

Comment: `$(el.target).closest('a').attr('href')` would be an alternative. Sometimes using `closest` makes sense, especially if you're using data attributes on a common container to hold bits of data.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know jQuery's closest() function. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
events: {
    'click a, click a i': 'navigate'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Well this does not work, too. But now I have a clue why this is going so wrong. The click event itself gets fired, BUT if you click on the i the event's target is not the a but the i element which has no href attribute and therefore can't forward to the correct route.

Comment: Can you post your own solution as an answer here when you've implemented it? I have a feeling I will run into this problem sooner or later. Will happily upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
events: {
    'click .btn': 'navigate'
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried giving the links a class but that also did not fix my problem (in fact it did not change anything of this behavior)...